# How to change color scheme of Win+X PowerShell shortcut?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, console, color-theme

So, to change the color scheme of normal cmd and powershell windows I used this, and it works:

https://wiki.mbirth.de/know-how/software/windows/tango-colours-console.html

However, I cannot find any way to change the color scheme of powershell windows opened from the Win+X menu, they always use the default colors, is there any way to do this?

The shortcuts are under:

C:\Users\rkito\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3

I tried replacing them, but that doesn't work, they are some kind of special `.lnk` files.

Comment: C:\Users\rkito\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3
when opening from here the power shell windows opens in black color and from win key+x it opens in blue color ...so??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are launching it manually and it works, it is done as admin user rkito, and that is indeed HKEY_CURRENT_USER in the registry. But Win+X stuff is ran under NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM so we will have to modify their registry keys, also.

Two HKEY_USERS subkeys are used by SYSTEM: S-1-5-19 is LocalService and S-1-5-20 is NetworkService. I also modify DEFAULT (==18) just to apply the setting to newly created users. And just to be safe. Blanket firing across all namespaces.

Solution: Replace HKEY_CURRENT_USER with HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18 .. HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20 to apply the color setting to all accounts.

Here is the entire *.reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Console]
; Black
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
; Blue
"ColorTable01"=dword:00a46534
; Green
"ColorTable02"=dword:00069a4e
; Cyan
"ColorTable03"=dword:009a9806
; Red
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000cc
; Magenta
"ColorTable05"=dword:007b5075
; Yellow
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000a0c4
; White
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cfd7d3
; Dark Gray (Light Black)
"ColorTable08"=dword:00535755
; Light Blue
"ColorTable09"=dword:00cf9f72
; Light Green
"ColorTable10"=dword:0034e28a
; Light Cyan
"ColorTable11"=dword:00e2e234
; Light Red
"ColorTable12"=dword:002929ef
; Light Magenta
"ColorTable13"=dword:00a87fad
; Light Yellow
"ColorTable14"=dword:004fe9fc
; Light White
"ColorTable15"=dword:00eceeee

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Console]
; Black
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
; Blue
"ColorTable01"=dword:00a46534
; Green
"ColorTable02"=dword:00069a4e
; Cyan
"ColorTable03"=dword:009a9806
; Red
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000cc
; Magenta
"ColorTable05"=dword:007b5075
; Yellow
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000a0c4
; White
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cfd7d3
; Dark Gray (Light Black)
"ColorTable08"=dword:00535755
; Light Blue
"ColorTable09"=dword:00cf9f72
; Light Green
"ColorTable10"=dword:0034e28a
; Light Cyan
"ColorTable11"=dword:00e2e234
; Light Red
"ColorTable12"=dword:002929ef
; Light Magenta
"ColorTable13"=dword:00a87fad
; Light Yellow
"ColorTable14"=dword:004fe9fc
; Light White
"ColorTable15"=dword:00eceeee

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Console]
; Black
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
; Blue
"ColorTable01"=dword:00a46534
; Green
"ColorTable02"=dword:00069a4e
; Cyan
"ColorTable03"=dword:009a9806
; Red
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000cc
; Magenta
"ColorTable05"=dword:007b5075
; Yellow
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000a0c4
; White
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cfd7d3
; Dark Gray (Light Black)
"ColorTable08"=dword:00535755
; Light Blue
"ColorTable09"=dword:00cf9f72
; Light Green
"ColorTable10"=dword:0034e28a
; Light Cyan
"ColorTable11"=dword:00e2e234
; Light Red
"ColorTable12"=dword:002929ef
; Light Magenta
"ColorTable13"=dword:00a87fad
; Light Yellow
"ColorTable14"=dword:004fe9fc
; Light White
"ColorTable15"=dword:00eceeee

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Console]
; Black
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
; Blue
"ColorTable01"=dword:00a46534
; Green
"ColorTable02"=dword:00069a4e
; Cyan
"ColorTable03"=dword:009a9806
; Red
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000cc
; Magenta
"ColorTable05"=dword:007b5075
; Yellow
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000a0c4
; White
"ColorTable07"=dword:00cfd7d3
; Dark Gray (Light Black)
"ColorTable08"=dword:00535755
; Light Blue
"ColorTable09"=dword:00cf9f72
; Light Green
"ColorTable10"=dword:0034e28a
; Light Cyan
"ColorTable11"=dword:00e2e234
; Light Red
"ColorTable12"=dword:002929ef
; Light Magenta
"ColorTable13"=dword:00a87fad
; Light Yellow
"ColorTable14"=dword:004fe9fc
; Light White
"ColorTable15"=dword:00eceeee

Edit reason: \. escape sequence caught me off guard.

Comment: for whatever reason it did not work for me, but I just converted the values to decimal and set it manually and then it works

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. By manually setting it do you mean you did it via regedit, or simply using the "Defaults" GUI of cmd.exe? The one titled: Console Windows Properties / "Command Prompt" Properties

Comment: I used the properties menu of the console. I clicked on the colors and put in the decimal values. I did this twice, once for running powershell from win+r and once for the powershell menu entry, which also worked for win+x entry.

Answer (score 0):

"powershell windows opened from the Win+X menu, they always use the default colors"
 - not true I just changed it.
near window title Right click >Properties>Colors Tab . then select the color you want.Close and open again.